# Working directory when running command

Tags: command-line, alias

I've got an executable, let's call it exec.  It lives in a directory, for the sake of argument called dir.  Let's say it's at the filesystem root.  I can run this executable by doing

```
cd /dir
./exec
```

If I try to run it from anywhere else, by doing

```
/dir/exec
```

it fails to run.  From the error message it spews out, it looks like it's trying to look for support files in the directory from which the command was run, not in its own directory.  So far not a massive problem.  However, I'd like to alias the command so I can call it from anywhere.  I can write an alias as follows:

```
alias foo="cd /dir;./exec &"
```

But that leaves my terminal in `/dir`, which I don't want.  I also don't want to change back to some arbitrary directory, I want to stay where I was.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, launch another shell:

```
alias foo="sh -c 'cd /dir; ./exec &'"
```

Or use a subshell:

```
alias foo="(cd /dir; ./exec &)"
```

Comment: Using a subshell is very simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:
suppose the file to execute anywhere is named: executeme

1. If it is not a executable file type the following command to maike it excutable

chmod +x executeme

1. If you are in the directory where the file is make a symbolic link to it in the bin directory(you must be root to do this)

sudo ln -s executeme /usr/bin/

1. If all is right you can now exute your file anywhere by typing the name of the file

executeme